# Git - What does -m mean

Tags: git

In `Git`, when we type for example:

```
$ git commit -m "xyz"
```

What does `-m` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the flag for the commit message.

Comment: -m is the message to describe your commit

Comment: Try `git help commit` and then *read* the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-m` stands for message - i.e., the commit message that everyone will see attached to your commit.

Comment: Feed a man a fish, he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, he'll eat for a lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

Snippet from `git commit --help`

```
-m <msg>, --message=<msg>
           Use the given <msg> as the commit message.
```

For every git command/action, you can type `git <command> --help` to get the documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is used to describe your commit, what you've done in this commit.
Your could check the man page by `man git-commit`, which will tell you more.